# Joomla search results

Tags: joomla

I am facing this issue that the search results page shows all the modules that I only show in the homepage. This happen after I deleted most of the sample data that comes with joomla. Before I deleted here is the url I got from the search:

```
localhost/my_site/index.php/using-joomla/extensions/components/search-component/search?searchword=cars&searchphrase=all
```

And now:

```
localhost/my_site/index.php/component/search/?searchword=cars&searchphrase=all&Itemid=643
```

So somehow there is a link between any sample menu item or category and the search page, how can I get back or recreate the same behavior so the search results page don't show the homepage modules?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found it, i had to set itemID (menu id) in the search module.